# MappedColumnType: Convert String to Vector[String] when MySQL column definition is Option[String] - ergo nullable

Tags: mysql, scala, slick

My goal is to populate the `filters` variable of the Slick entity with a `Vector[String]` which is produced from parsing the `String` stored in the filters column of MySQL.

A simplified version of the Slick and MySQL table definitions I have are the following:

```
object Something {

    class Something(tag: Tag) extends Table[SomethingRow](tag, "SOMETHING") {

        def filters = column[Vector[String]]("FILTERS")

        override def * = (filters).mapTo[SomethingRow]
    }

}
```

the case class used to map the db row is:

```scala
case class SomethingRow(filters: Vector[String])
```

```
create table SOMETHING (
    filters varchar(128);
);
```

In order to enable this conversion I have defined the following implicits:

```scala
    implicit val stringToVectorMapper = MappedColumnType.base[Vector[String], String](
        { vctr =>
            if (vctr == null || vctr.isEmpty) StringUtils.EMPTY
            else vctr.mkString(",")
        },
        { str =>
            if (StringUtils.isEmpty(str)) Vector.empty
            else str.split(",").toVector
        })
```

which I import in the `Something` class and the corresponding repository

The error I am getting is the following:

```
play.api.http.HttpErrorHandlerExceptions$$anon$1: Execution exception[[SlickException: Read NULL value (null) for ResultSet column <computed>]]
    at play.api.http.HttpErrorHandlerExceptions$.throwableToUsefulException(HttpErrorHandler.scala:255)
    at play.api.http.DefaultHttpErrorHandler.onServerError(HttpErrorHandler.scala:182)
    at play.core.server.AkkaHttpServer$$anonfun$2.applyOrElse(AkkaHttpServer.scala:310)
```

I assume I am taking care of the `null` case in the definition of the `stringToVectorMapper` but I suppose this is not enough.

If I change the definition of the mapper to the following:

```scala
implicit val stringToVectorMapper = MappedColumnType.base[Vector[String], Option[String]](
        { vctr =>
            if (vctr == null || vctr.isEmpty) None
            else Some(vctr.mkString(","))
        },
        { str =>
            if (str.isEmpty) Vector.empty
            else str.get.split(",").toVector
        })
```

I am getting a no implicits found error:

```
No implicits found for evidence: MySQLProfile.BaseColumnType[Option[String]]
```

Comment: I worked around this by adding an empty `String` as a default value for the `filters` column in the database so that it won't be null but this is not a solution. The question remains: How can one define a Slick custom data type for a nullable db column.